# Jackson deserializing GMaps JSON

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize the following JSON: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=04545-006

My doubt is, how to I deserialize it in a way I only get results.geometry.location.lat and results.geometry.location.lng ?

Since I am using Spring, I tried using RestTemplate and annotate the helper class as follow, without success:

```
public class GmapsDto {

t@JsonProperty("results/geometry/location/lat")
private String lat;

@JsonProperty("results.geometry.location.lng")
private String lng;

public String getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(String lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public String getLng() {
    return lng;
}

public void setLng(String lng) {
    this.lng = lng;
}
}
```

Is there a way to navigate through the object tree and get only the info I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want be able to use a simple navigation via annotations, there has been a JIRA issue reported for a @JsonWrapped annotation, opposite to @JsonUnwrapped, which is basically what you're saying http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-781. In my humble opinion the simplest way for you would be to navigate the tree and lean on the JsonNode, something like

```
    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readValue(gmapJson, JsonNode.class); 
    System.out.println(rootNode.findValues("location"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Jackson JIRA had a ticket for `@JsonWrapped` annotation for deserializing to "flat" objects like your `GMapsDto`. Unfortunately, [it was closed](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-781), and has not yet re-appeared at [jackson-databind issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues).

In addition, you can have **multiple results**, because `results` is actually a JSON array, not an object.

So I see two possible routes.

1. To use Jackson for custom serialization/deserialization, annotate your class with `@JsonDeserialize` and implement a custom deserializer using Jackson's Tree API.

   This deserializes all results as instances of `GMapsDto`:

   ```
   // in GMapsResult.java
   public class GMapsResult {
       private final List<GMapsDto> results;

       @JsonCreator
       public GMapsResult(@JsonProperty("results") List<GMapsDto> results) { this.results = results; }

       public List<GMapsDto> getResults() { return results; }
   }

   // in GMapsDto.java
   @JsonDeserialize(using = GMapsDto.Deserializer.class) 
   public class GMapsDto {
       // ...

       private static final class Deserializer extends JsonDeserializer<GMapsDto> {
           @Override
           public GMapsDto deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
                   throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                   JsonNode location = jp.readValueAsTree()
                           .path("geometry")
                           .path("location");

                   GMapsDto dto = new GMapsDto();
                   dto.setLat(location.get("lat").doubleValue());
                   dto.setLon(location.get("lat").doubleValue());
                   return dto;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Annotate your class with `@JsonCreator` and create bogus inner classes representing JSON keys `results`, `geometry` and `location`, e.g.:

   ```
   public final class GMapsDto {
       private final List<Results> results;        

       @JsonCreator
       public GMapsDto(@JsonProperty("results") List<Results> results) {this.results = results;}

       public List<Result> getResults() { return results; }

       public static final class Result {
           private final Geometry geometry;

           @JsonCreator
           public Result(@JsonProperty("geometry") Geometry geometry) {this.geometry = geometry;}

           public Geometry getGeometry() { return geometry; }

           public static final class Geometry {
               private final Location location;

               @JsonCreator
               public Geometry(@JsonProperty("location") Location location) { this.location = location; }

               public Location getLocation() { return location; }

               public static final class Location {
                   private final double lat;
                   private final double lon;

                   @JsonCreator
                   public Geometry(@JsonProperty("lat") double lat, @JsonProperty("lon") double lon) {
                       this.lat = lat; 
                       this.lon = lon; 
                   }

                   public double getLat() { return lat; }
                   public double getLon() { return lon; }
               }
           }
       }        
   }
   ```

   Then you would access latitude and longitude for each result:

   ```
   for (Result result: dto.getResults()) { 
       double {lat|lon} = result.getGeometry().getLocation().get{Lat(),Lon()};
   }
   ```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your detailed reply. I tried using your first solution and jp.readValueAsTree().get("results").get("geometry") returns null, even though jp.readValueAsTree().get("results") returns something

Comment: Hmmm. What does get("results") return? It should be an `ObjectNode`.

Comment: Also, to avoid NPEs in intermediate results, you could use `JsonNode location = jp.readValueAsTree().path("results").path("geometry").path("location")`

Comment: Ahh! I see what the problem is. `results` is an array, I'll update my code in a sec

Comment: You may also consider using `JsonNode.at(JsonPointer)`, which is the implementation of [JSON Pointer Specification](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-json-pointer-03), sorta like XPath for JSON.

Comment: Even though you answer worked, I found the other answer simpler to implement. Anyway, thanks both for the awesome help.